# Selenium WebDriver Chrome could not be started in Powershell

Tags: powershell, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to start the web automation with using Chrome driver and Selenium. But I am getting an error that, web driver was not loaded. Below is my code entered. If someone could help me to correct this and start to automate would be appreciated.

```
Import-Module 'C:\AHKM\ChromeAutomation\WebDriver.dll'
$WebDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver
$WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl('www.google.com')
```

Error is below:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:9
+         $WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl('www.google.com')
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Can you check with the URL along with the protocol like `https://www.google.com`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But its not at all starting the chrome app. And its saying that, WARNING: Web driver was not created

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this issue by supplying the folder where chromedriver.exe is located, e.g.

```
$WebDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver -ArgumentList "C:\TEMP"
```